# Is this true: $\ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{i}{n-i} \right) = e$?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits

I was doing the old thing where you play with numbers (with help of my calculator) and came across what seems to be an interesting observation:

$$\ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{i}{n-i} \right) = e.$$

At least, this seems to be what is happening with low values of $\ n\ $ with my calculator. So I'm not certain it is correct.

Is this correct, and why? How do we change the left hand side into an integral? I totally forgot how to do this. Or can we prove it with one of the definitions of $\ e\ ?$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Firstly, for $i = n$ the summand becomes $\frac n 0$.

Comment: these limits are Riemman sums, looks like you've got $\int _0^1 \frac{1}{\frac1x -1}dx$, which diverges

Comment: The term corresponding to $i=n$ is undefined.

Comment: yeah, but you better check it out. The fact that $i=n$ gives a division by zero may indicate you're looking at a wrong problem. Not well defined at  least.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about the title. Just edited that now also.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true.

Write $S_n = \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}\frac i{n - i}$. Adding $1$ to each summand, we get $$n + S_n = \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}\frac n{n - i} = n\sum_{i = 1}^n\frac 1 i = nH_n$$where $H_n$ denotes the [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

From this, it's clear that the limit diverges, as the harmonic numbers do.